# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object.......................?

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable

I am having a problem when trying to pass an Object reference from an Activity to another and I believe the culprit is the a List that I have as a field on this object. The reason I believe that is because when I change the list to transient, the object seems to be able to pass, but of course that does not solve my problem, since now the list is null in the new Activity.

Code for the Source Activity

```
    package com.example.animequiz.ui.activity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.animequiz.R;
import com.example.animequiz.dao.AnimeDAO;
import com.example.animequiz.model.Anime;
import com.example.animequiz.ui.adapter.AnimeListAdapter;

import java.util.List;

import static com.example.animequiz.ui.activity.HomePageActivityConstants.KEY_ANIME;

public class AnimesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime);
        configureAnimeList();
    }

    private void configureAnimeList() {
        ListView animeList = findViewById(R.id.activity_anime_listview);
        final List<Anime> animes = new AnimeDAO().list();
        animeList.setAdapter(new AnimeListAdapter(animes, this));
        animeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Anime selectedAnime = animes.get(position);
                goToLevels(selectedAnime);
            }
        });
    }

    private void goToLevels(Anime selectedAnime) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AnimesActivity.this, LevelsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_ANIME, selectedAnime);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Code for Anime class

```
    package com.example.animequiz.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Anime implements Serializable {

    private final String title;
    private final String image;
    private final List<Level> levelList;

    public Anime(String title, String image, List<Level> levelList) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.levelList = levelList;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public double getAnimeCompletionPercentage() {
        double animeCompletionPercentage = 0;
        for (Level level: levelList) {
            animeCompletionPercentage += level.getLevelCompletionPercentage();
        }
        animeCompletionPercentage = animeCompletionPercentage/levelList.size();
        return animeCompletionPercentage;
    }

    public List<Level> getLevelList() {
        return levelList;
    }

}
```

Code for Level

```
package com.example.animequiz.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Level implements Serializable {

    private final List<AnimeCharacter> animeCharacterList;

    public Level(List<AnimeCharacter> animeCharacterList) {
        this.animeCharacterList = animeCharacterList;
    }

    public double getLevelCompletionPercentage() {
        double levelCompletionPercentage = 0;
        for (AnimeCharacter animeCharacter: animeCharacterList) {
            if (animeCharacter.isKnownByPlayer() == true)
                levelCompletionPercentage++;
        }
        levelCompletionPercentage = levelCompletionPercentage/animeCharacterList.size();
        return levelCompletionPercentage;
    }

    public List<AnimeCharacter> getAnimeCharacterList() {
        return animeCharacterList;
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
04-09 17:29:28.296 13995-13995/com.example.animequiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.animequiz, PID: 13995
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.animequiz.model.Anime)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1394)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7485)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2411)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
        at com.example.animequiz.ui.activity.AnimesActivity.goToLevels(AnimesActivity.java:46)
        at com.example.animequiz.ui.activity.AnimesActivity.access$000(AnimesActivity.java:21)
        at com.example.animequiz.ui.activity.AnimesActivity$1.onItemClick(AnimesActivity.java:38)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3872)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3637)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
        at android.view
```

Comment: Can you post whats inside the Level class? If you want `Anime` class to be serializable all of its properties should be an instance of a serializable class also. Meaning that `Level` class should be serializable too

Comment: Just drop this serializable mambo jambo. Use Gson. Very flexible, very powerful. Use Gson.toJson, to pass a string to the other side. Than use Gson.fromJson to rebuild the object.

Comment: @RezoShalikashvili I just edited it to include the code for Level.class

Comment: @gmfiga So Java serialization works like a tree. It starts from the root class in your case 'Anime'. Every property of that class should be serializable. It goes recursively in properties. So in your case 'Level' class has property of type 'AnimeCharacter'. It means that 'AnimeCharacter' should also be serializable. And so on. Until you reach the promotive types like string and numbers. Also very important that serializable class should have zero argument constructor. I'll write full answer with examples if you want. You can ignore this and use gson also. But understand this will be useful.

Comment: @RezoShalikashvili you are right. I completely forgot about implementing Serializable on my AnimeCharacter.class. It worked out well now. Thank you!

Comment: @RezoShalikashvili could you please post your explanation as an answer so I can mark the question as answered? Thank you

Comment: @gmfiga here you go. Thanks 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Java serialization works like a tree. It starts from the root class in your case `Anime`. Every property of that class should be serializable. It goes recursively in properties. So in your case '`Level`' class has property of type '`AnimeCharacter`'. It means that '`AnimeCharacter`' should also be serializable. And so on. Until you reach the promotive types like string and numbers. Also very important that serializable class should have zero argument constructor. You can ignore this and use '`Gson`' also. But understanding this will be useful in future because all serialization engines work in similar fashion.